# Div element walk with scrolling, smooth

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have just started a new website. It's important for me that the users sees this container, so I want it to scroll with the site.

I have an example for this thing: http://gruen-weiss-mannheim.de/

> On this site on the left its a green container who stays with smooth scroll on the site if someone scrolls.

I hope you can help me, because I have already tried something, but in this way the container is always on the top.

Would be great If you could help me find a solution!

```js
try {
 window.onscroll = setNavPosition;
 }
 catch(e) {
 document.documentElement.onscroll = setNavPosition;
 }
 function setNavPosition(){
 $('.smooth').stop();
 try {
 if (document.body.scrollTop > document.documentElement.scrollTop) {
 var targetPosition = document.body.scrollTop;
 }
 else {
 var targetPosition = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
 }
 }
 catch(e) {
 var targetPosition = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
 }
 $('.smooth').animate({top: targetPosition}, 600);
 }
```

```css
.smooth {
height: 40px;
background-color: orange;
z-index: 2;
position: absolute;
width: 50px;
top: 50px;
}

.body {
height: 700px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="body"></div>

<div class="smooth"></div>
```

So every time I scroll, the container gets back to the top, not with the space in between...

Comment: In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the **question itself**. External sites may be malicious, flagged by filter systems, or removed at a later stage (rendering your question useless). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you mean is that after the first scrolling it always stops by the edge of the viewport, it is because of this lines `var targetPosition = document.body.scrollTop;` and `var targetPosition = document.documentElement.scrollTop;`. I changed them:

```js
try {
 window.onscroll = setNavPosition;
 }
 catch(e) {
 document.documentElement.onscroll = setNavPosition;
 }
 function setNavPosition(){
 $('.smooth').stop();
 try {
 if (document.body.scrollTop > document.documentElement.scrollTop) {
 var targetPosition = document.body.scrollTop + 50;
 }
 else {
 var targetPosition = document.documentElement.scrollTop + 50;
 }
 }
 catch(e) {
 var targetPosition = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
 }
 $('.smooth').animate({top: targetPosition}, 600);
 }
```

```css
.smooth {
height: 40px;
background-color: orange;
z-index: 2;
position: absolute;
width: 50px;
top: 50px;
}

.body {
height: 700px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="body"></div>

<div class="smooth"></div>
```